# Looping with online algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, matrix, sapply

This maybe a newbie question but I'm trying to apply an online algorithm in a loop in R. Essentially, this is just a function that updates certain variables every step in a loop. I have a lot of matrices that I would like to apply this "online function" to and have the variables in the online function update in every step of the loop. The matrices look like this:

```
x


          [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
[1,] 0.0294067658 1.116547e-02 1.2674784332 0.0000000000 6.994836e-03 8.222123e-01
[2,] 0.0000000000 4.384807e+00 0.0099189102 0.0000000000 1.071928e+01 1.619473e-02
[3,] 0.0000000000 2.047100e-02 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 1.282887e-02 4.370000e+00
[4,] 1.2600000000 2.145952e-02 0.0143775046 0.0198709933 1.344862e-02 2.347032e-02
[5,] 0.0584418001 2.219845e-02 0.0148727323 0.8905552563 0.000000e+00 2.427843e-02
[6,] 0.0602240425 0.000000e+00 0.0153266127 0.0211823892 1.433646e-02 8.350191e-01
[7,] 0.0361660755 1.071000e+01 0.0091998143 0.0127169064 8.605112e-03 1.502130e-02
[8,] 0.0000000000 2.940000e+00 0.0020833114 0.0028839352 1.947935e-03 3.408502e-03
```

When I try implementing this I end up getting just NaNs

```
n=10
for (i in 1:n) {
  x <- rad(x) # rad just introduces some randomness into the matrix at every step
  test <- as.matrix(sapply(x, online_fun))
}

test

 [1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[22] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[43] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

The online algorithm I am trying to implement is from this website, which I modified slightly for R (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). online_fun looks like this:

```
online_fun = function(data) {
b = 0
mean = 0
M2 = 0
 for (x in data){
   b = b + 1
   delta = x - mean
   mean = mean + delta/b
   M2 = M2 + delta*(x - mean)}
variance = M2/(b - 1)
return(variance) 
}
```

Since I'm using R, I think I'm having issues transferring the python code from the website into R format. Any ideas as to how I can get this to work?

---

**EDIT**

Okay this works. But the variance values are way too high. I think I am not writing out the online_fun correctly. The variance values should stay within a range of 0 to 1 since each matrix does not get larger than 1.

```
n=10
newdata=matrix(NA,length(x),length(x))
output=NULL

for (i in 1:length(x)){newdata[i,]=as.numeric(rad(x))}
for (b in 1:length(x)){output[b]=online_fun(newdata[,b])}
varout <- matrix(output,dim(x)[1],dim(x)[2])

varout

        [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]        [,6]
[1,] 0.004966027 1.4571354  0.2684045 11.1530038  0.6162148  0.09535756
[2,] 0.076392842 0.4229576  8.2096252  3.7317939 20.4273919 10.84911306
[3,] 0.203111586 0.7832483  2.9868466 23.7188088 31.7876892 21.87255841 
[4,] 0.196244671 0.3244376  4.3041476 14.3199122 14.9616231  0.05155568 
[5,] 0.450541223 2.2755737  0.0000000 24.4974883  0.0000000 16.34079758 
[6,] 0.212475849 3.2150916  0.9512643 24.2388946 26.6973032  1.66855735 
[7,] 0.028548367 7.1019461  0.9410647  4.5740047 10.8723574  0.00000000 
[8,] 0.716404545 6.0821764  1.1903668 38.1787544 11.3333774  5.55307623
```

Comment: Surely x is supposed to be a dataframe? It looks like its a matrix.

Comment: x is supposed to be a matrix that is 8X6.

Comment: But if x is a matrix then sapply calls the function online_fun with only one argument, which means you're trying to compute the variance of a single number, which seems uninformative.

Comment: Also this means you only go through the `for x in data` loop once, which means `b=1`, and you are dividing by zero. If you want to apply the online_fun to the rows or columns, use `apply`

Comment: I did what you suggested. But I am trying to compute variance for each cell entry and update that matrix in the next step in the loop. So you can think of it as variance across cell entries for different matrices.

Comment: okay this works.but I do not know how to fix your third comment. 

n=10
newdata=matrix(NA,length(x),length(x))
output=NULL

for (i in 1:length(x)){newdata[i,]=as.numeric(rad(x))}
for (b in 1:length(x)){output[b]=online_fun(newdata[,b])}
varout <- matrix(output,dim(x)[1],dim(x)[2])

Comment: If I understand you, you have say 100 matrices and you want the variance of x[i,j] over the 100 for each i and j. The code you just posted looks promising - it wasn't going to work with the initial approach.

Comment: You mean using apply? I wouldn't worry about that if what you have works. Your new code looks like it would remove the divide by zero error.

Comment: this is performing what I want but the variance is way too high. The calculated values should stay within 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your online_fun and it computes the variance just fine (compare with the var function in R). Not sure why the variance is not behaving as you expect. I see numbers greater than 1 in your posted data.

Note that the Python code you copied from wikipedia only works right with Python3.